# wordpress data serialize in corresponding order

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization

In wordpress I have stored the data as serialize method means for title the 1st row named as title[1], 2nd row title[2] and for the 3rd its title[3] and so on. This method is the same for all fields(name,phone). After storing the data as serialize now I want to fetch the data. So to fetch I have my script like this

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `table` where `id` = 4");
```

now when I am doing print_r($results); I am getting the result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => a:3:{i:1;s:8:"title1";i:2;s:8:"title2";i:0;s:0:"title3";}
            [name] => a:3:{i:1;s:8:"name1";i:2;s:8:"name2";i:0;s:0:"name3";}
            [phone] => a:3:{i:1;s:8:"123";i:2;s:8:"324";i:0;s:0:"648";}

        )

)
```

To use the data I have used unserilize and foreach like this

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $titles = unserialize($result->title);
    $names = unserialize($result->name);
    $phones = unserialize($result->phone);

    foreach($titles as $title) {
        echo $title;
    }
}
```

But this doesnot make sense as because I want all the attributes like (id, title, name, phone) for the same row means for 1st row it should show all the values for 1st element.so the data should show like this

```
Id  Title    Name    Phone
4   title1   name1   123
4   title2   name2   324
4   title3   name3   648
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming the same number of items are in each array.  The ID also isn't available.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</td>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php   
foreach($results as $result) {
    $titles = unserialize($result->title);
    $names = unserialize($result->name);
    $phones = unserialize($result->phone);

    $i=0;
    foreach($titles as $title) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "  <td>4</td>\n"; // This isn't in your serialized data.  I'll let you work out where it comes from.
        echo '  <td>'. $titles[$i] .'</td>'. "\n";
        echo '  <td>'. $names[$i] .'</td>'. "\n";
        echo '  <td>'. $phones[$i] .'</td>'. "\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";

        $i++;
    }
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```